# Safari doesn't respect Cache-Control HTTP headers?

Tags: django, http, safari

Using a variety of resources, I've come up with the following django middleware to prevent browser caching for authenticated users:

```
class NoBrowserCachingMiddleware:
    def add_to_header(self, response, key, value):
        if response.has_header(key):
            values = re.split(r'\s*,\s*', response[key])
            if not value in values:
                response[key] = ', '.join(values + [value])
        else:
            response[key] = value

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated():
            response['Expires'] = 0
            self.add_to_header(response, 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
            self.add_to_header(response, 'Cache-Control', 'no-store')
            self.add_to_header(response, 'Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate')
            self.add_to_header(response, 'Pragma', 'no-cache') #HTTP 1.0
            if request.is_ajax():
                return response
            if response.status_code != 200:
                return response
            if 'text/html' not in response['Content-Type']:
                return response

            # safari back button fix
            response.content = response.content.replace('<body', '<body onunload=""')

        return response
```

I would like to remove the piece where I have to modify the response content. If I do, however, Safari will display the previous cached page after a logout if the user hits the back button. Is there any way to prevent this using standard HTTP headers?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Practically, if the user logs out then goes back to the previous page, what's the big worry? They could have that site open in 5 tabs, so even if you prevented them going back, you couldn't prevent them necessarily seeing info once they've logged out. Their session will be dead, though, so any new actions (eg acting on a form in the  expired page, or trying to access a protected view linked from that page) should require them to authenticated again, so there's no great worry. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is a big problem in the banking industry, health care, etc... The code above along with some javascript on the client DOES prevent them. These HTTP headers are often used to prevent exactly this scenario.

Comment: Even if modifying response.content isn't ideal I couldn't figure out how to prevent the safari back button issue so thanks for posting this solution!

Comment: `# safari back button fix` doesn't work.

Comment: It's the new IE